# Soldering QFP with thermal pad (but with obstructions/no vias on underside)

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, solder-paste

I will start by saying that I'm a complete newbie when it comes to soldering SMD. I've been practicing with scrap boards, and I'm getting there, but not sure how to approach this one.

I am trying to replace a TSB81BA3E, which is in HTQFP package i.e. QFP with a PowerPAD underneath. I managed to desolder the broken chip OK with hot air (hard work!) and have cleaned all the pads/removed solder from the old thermal pad.

All the guides I've seen on how to solder this chip involve heating/applying solder to vias from the underside. Unfortunately this board has SMD components on the underside, and no vias to heat through. I also feel like I can't put the board in an oven as there are a lot of plastic connectors on it.

My proposed approach is the following:

1. Pre-heat board to 150c or so, using heat gun at a distance (and
   laser temperature gun to assess temp.)
2. Apply tin/bismuth solder to central pad
3. Apply Sn63/Pb37 solder paste to pins
4. Heat chip at somewhere around 220 degrees until it appears to seat itself (datasheet specifies max 260 degrees for 10 seconds on this chip, so say max. 30 secs at 220 degrees?)

Does this sound reasonable? My thinking for using the tin/bismuth is its lower melting point - I'm imagining the reduced strength of its joints would be OK used on a large area such as thermal pad.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it sounds reasonable for the most part. But why are you using low temp solder for the center pad? If the IC heats up to 100 C, then the solder may reflow and short the neighboring pins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I had thought that too. I'm just concerned that if I use Sn63/Pb37 on the pad I won't be able to correctly reflow the solder on the pad by applying heat just to the top of the IC... I would be effectively heating the pad through the IC body.

Comment: What you can do is add Sn63/Pb37 solder onto the thermal pad, and then use your hot air station to slowly heat up the PCB and the IC. The key is to get the board hot enough to where the solder will reflow. And as long as your patient, that will happen. Just be careful with the amount of solder you apply. If you add too much, then the IC will not make contact with the other pads.

Comment: Noted - that makes sense to me, thank you.